# What is an efficient way of writing sum from i = 1 to n, log(1 + exp(w_i)) in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, math

Let `w = (w_1, w_2, w_3, ...., w_n)` be an array, `n` is large

Without using loops, I want to define the function

> sum from i = 1 to i = n, `log(1 + exp(w_i))`

Is there a vector operation that handles this in Numpy? I was thinking of

```
np.dot(np.ones((n,)), np.log(1+np.exp(w))
```

but I don't know if that works.

Comment: No need to use `np.dot`... There's `np.sum(...)`. The rest should be fine.

Comment: `np.log(1+np.exp(array)).sum()`?

Comment: There's also `np.log1p(...)` specifically for the case of 1 + something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.sum(...)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to sum all elements of the array.

While `np.log(1+np.exp(w))` should work fine, there's also [`np.log1p(...)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html#numpy.log1p) which calculates the ln of one plus values with better precision in case of very small numbers.

Putting it all together:

```
result = np.sum(np.log1p(np.exp(w)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know numpy automatically knew that sum means to sum all the components of the array.